# Calculate the Sample Median from Grouped Data

Tags: statistics, education, descriptive-statistics, median

I have this grouped data.

Income = below 5000, 5001 - 10000, 10001 - 20000, 20001 - 40000, 40001 - 100000, 100001 - 200000, above 200000

F(Income) = 59, 101, 153, 207, 223, 44, 6

How do I find the Median Income, especially the midpoint? I have problem with dealing with **Below 5000** and **Above 200000**

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  How many of your data points are $<10000.5$, say?  How many are $<20000.5$?  In this way you should at least find out which bucket contains the median.  Now, beyond that you can't say much without making some assumption about how income within a bucket is distributed.

Comment: Thanks @lulu I have got it sorted out. Bruce actually gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The median lies somewhere in the 4th interval (the one with frequency 207).
There are various interpolation procedures for making assumptions
and guessing *where* in the interval. If your book discusses
one of these, I suggest you try to figure out how to use it.
Often, it is good enough to say which interval is the 'median interval'.
[The open-ended first and last intervals cause difficulty if you are guessing
at the sample *mean,* but not for the *median.*]

In the table below `cf` stands for *cumulative frequency* and `crf` for *cumulative relative frequency.*

```
 i   f  cf    crf      
 1  59  59 0.0744
 2 101 160 0.2018
 3 153 313 0.3947
 4 207 520 0.6557  <-- This interval: First crf > .5
 5 223 743 0.9369
 6  44 787 0.9924
 7   6 793 1.0000
```

Comment: A commonly used interpolation formula is used in [_this Q & A_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617208/calculation-of-median-of-grouped-data/1617407#1617407) and other pages mentioned there. Maybe also see "Related" pages linked in the right margin here.

Comment: Thanks so very much @BruceET, this is very much helpful.