# Finding the (not) median from a histogram

Tags: median

This question is related to [How to find median from a histogram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591946/how-to-find-median-from-a-histogram)

A common problem is to estimate a median from a histogram, where 50% of the numbers are below the median, and 50% are above.

I would like to do this, but for some fraction other than 50%. I don't know if this is still called the median, or if it has some other name. (let's call it the Fractian for the purposes of this question).

I would like to estimate the value where f% of the numbers are below the value, and (100-f)% are above the value:

For example, here I am showing an estimate of the 33% fractian in these three histograms:
[image: Not median from histogram]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is certainly NOT called the median!  Determining some other value is just a matter of finding where P(x) is equal to whatever fraction you want.  And how you do that depends on the probability function itself!

Comment: Thank you, but *how* do I do that. I don't know the probability function, I just have the array of numbers.

Comment: If you "have the array of numbers" then you have the probability!